# Fast sorting of large nested lists

Tags: python, performance, list, python-2.7, count

I am looking to find out the likelihood of parameter combinations using Monte Carlo Simulation.
I've got 4 parameters and each can have about 250 values.
I have randomly generated 250,000 scenarios for each of those parameters using some probability distribution function.
I now want to find out which parameter combinations are the most likely to occur.
To achieve this I have started by filtering out any duplicates from my 250,000 randomly generated samples in order to reduce the length of the list.
I then iterated through this reduced list and checked how many times each scenario occurs in the original 250,000 long list.

I have a large list of 250,000 items which contains lists, as such :

```
a = [[1,2,5,8],[1,2,5,8],[3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,7],....,[3,4,5,7]]# len(a) is equal to 250,000
```

I want to find a fast and efficient way of having each list within my list only occurring once.

The end goal is to count the occurrences of each list within list a.

so far I've got:

```
'''Removing duplicates from list a and storing this as a new list temp'''
b_set = set(tuple(x) for x in a)
temp = [ list(x) for x in b_set ]
temp.sort(key = lambda x: a.index(x) )    

''' I then iterate through each of my possible lists (i.e. temp) and count how many times they occur in a'''
most_likely_dict = {}
for scenario in temp:
    freq = list(scenario_list).count(scenario)
    most_likely_dict[str(scenario)] = freq
```

at the moment it takes a good 15 minutes to perform ... Any suggestion on how to turn that into a few seconds would be greatly appreciated !!

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve with this? It's likely that if you need two re-sort the list every time you're doing something sub-optimal. Could you provide some context?

Comment: I have added a bit of context at the start of the question. I basically want to know how many time each list within the large list occurs. Each nested list represents a possible combination of parameters for my problem and rather than model all possible combinations I want to focus on the 4 most likely ones.

Comment: Why don't you just do [`Counter(map(tuple, a))`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)? This will give you e.g. `{(1, 2, 5, 8): 2, ...}`, without the need to sort.

Comment: Thanks that's just what I needed ! I didn't know about Counter. Can you post this as an answer so I can accept it ?? Thanks

Comment: It appears to already be in one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take out the sorting part, as the final result is a dictionary which will be unordered in any case, then use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[1,2],[3,4,5],[3,4,5], [3,4,5]]
>>> a_tupled = [tuple(i) for i in a]
>>> b_set = set(a_tupled)
>>> {repr(i): a_tupled.count(i) for i in b_set}
{'(1, 2)': 2, '(3, 4, 5)': 3}
```

calling `list` on your tuples will add more overhead, but you can if you want to

```
>>> {repr(list(i)): a_tupled.count(i) for i in b_set}
{'[3, 4, 5]': 3, '[1, 2]': 2}
```

Or just use a `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(tuple(i) for i in a)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{str(item):a.count(item) for item in a}
```

Input :

```
a = [[1,2,5,8],[1,2,5,8],[3,4,5,6],[3,4,5,7],[3,4,5,7]]
```

Output :

```
{'[3, 4, 5, 6]': 1, '[1, 2, 5, 8]': 2, '[3, 4, 5, 7]': 2}
```

Comment: Note that this is `O(n^2)`, as `count` iterates the whole list every time.